# Организация ассоциаций в JPA

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Есть сущность:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "cases")

public class Case {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String caseNumber;

    private String dataI;

    private String dataII;

    private String dataIII;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Judge judge;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Lawyer lawyer;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Client client;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus statusI;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus statusII;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus statusIII;

    private String document;

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Как видите есть поля **judge, lawyer, client** (ассоциированные). Получаю в сервисе:

```
public List<Case> findAll() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getAllCases");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Тестирую в сервлете, получаю ошибку NullPointerException. Теперь вопрос: **как правильно организовать ассоциации?**. Метод findAll() возвращает все обьекты, но не во всех полях сущностей оказывается "целым" поле lawyer, case, client. То есть в таблице у меня 20 дел, адвокатов 10. 1 адвокат мог вести больше одного дела, а findAll(), я так понял, возвращает первые попавшиеся ассоциированные 10 дел с 10-ю адвокатами, а остальные дела с null-адвокатами. Пробовал и @ManyToOne и @OneToMany, не могу точно понять что именно использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ManyToOne
private Judge judge;// в классе Case

@ManyToOne
private Client client;// в классе Case

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "judge")
private Set<Case> cases = new HashSet<>();// в классе Judge 

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "client")
private Set<Case> cases = new HashSet<>();// в классе Client 

public List<Case> findAll() {
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select c from Case c left join fetch c.lawyer left join fetch c.judge left join fetch c.client", Case.class);
return query.getResultList();
}
```

обязательно переопредели hashCode  и equals у всех классов

Comment: А если еще и судьи, и клиенты?

Comment: обновил комментарий

Comment: Спасибо, уже лучше! Теперь хоть деплоится приложение, не считая  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: **Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'case0_.judge_id' in 'field list'**

Comment: проверь, создалось ли в базе данных такое поле у сущности Case?

Comment: Все получилось. В базе данных на месте обьектов judge, client, lawyer были соответственно целочисленные поля judgeID, clientID, lawyerID. В сущность Case добавил **@JoinColumn()** с **name** названия поля. Спасибо тебе огромное)

Comment: Чуть обновил, перед всеми join fetch поставил left, это чтобы правильно работал запрос. Не забывай про hashCode и equals (включай в них все примитивы). Ну и сам вопрос закрой, если все работает.